# How to count white pixels in every blob in opencv?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm looking for a simple and elegant way to count white pixels in every blob individually. For example I have picture like this:

[image: black and white image]

Code:

```
cv2.findContours(mat.copy(), cv2.RETR_LIST, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
areas = [(lambda c: cv2.moments(c)['m00'])(c) for c in contours]
```

returns [255.0, 482.5, 6480.5, 6230.0, 15531.0, 19810.0], but I want to have just 3 values as there are 3 separate blobs.

Comment: Do you want the area of each blob ??  What makes you think that there are only three blobs?? Two or more pixels together are considered as a blob !!

Comment: @Arjun what? There are 3 white blobs here.

Comment: @dragon7 you proposed a solution based on `connectedComponentsWithStats`. If that works, can you make a new answer with a code example, and mark that as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option seems to be using [connectedComponentsWithStats](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=connectedcomponents#connectedcomponents) from OpenCV 3.0.

Example:

```
# find all blobs and label them
n, labels, stats, _ = cv2.connectedComponentsWithStats(mat)
```

- **n** - number of different blobs
- **labels** - matrix with the same shape like mat and contains label for every point
- **stats** - statistics for every blob in following order:

  - `CC_STAT_LEFT` The leftmost (x) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the horizontal direction.
  - `CC_STAT_TOP` The topmost (y) coordinate which is the inclusive start of the bounding box in the vertical direction.
  - `CC_STAT_WIDTH` The horizontal size of the bounding box
  - `CC_STAT_HEIGHT` The vertical size of the bounding box
  - `CC_STAT_AREA` The total area (in pixels) of the connected component

So if you want to know how many pixels are in given blob, just check the row equals to label and fifth column.